# É possível criar um arquivo virtual no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Estou tentando usar um arquivo m3u modificado, porem não quero gerar um arquivo físico pra isso**

Gerando o arquvio fisico:

```
url = "#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:6.006400...."

arquivo = open("movies.m3u8", "w+")
arquivo.write(url)
arquivo.close()
```

**Gostaria de fazer o mesmo processo só que como um arquivo virtual sem precisar criar um arquivo físico na maquina, é possível?**

Comment: Não seria apenas não gravar o campo `url`? A variável não seria o tal do "arquivo virtual"?

Comment: No caso para reprodução ele precisa executar o arquivo alocado como .m3u8, modo direto pela url não funciona

Comment: Você já pensou em redirecionamento de entrada e saída? Se o seu problema é manter um arquivo gravado em seu disco.

Comment: Como seria isso? pode dar um exemplo

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirecionamento_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Vou dar uma lida, obrigado

Comment: Pessoal - só reiterando uma consideração: se você não consegue entender uma pergunta, pode ser só por que você ainda não tem o conhecimento necessário para responde-la - evitem negativar uma pergunta só por isso. Nesse caso, por exemplo, a resposta é simples e única na forma de uma funcionalidade na própria linguagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim - em Python 3, há o módulo `io` - e dentro dele, as classes `BytesIO` para criar o que você chama de "arquivo virtual"(*) binário, e StringIO para fazer o mesmo com um arquivo de texto.

Os objetos dessa classe tem os métodos `write`, `read`, `seek` e outros para "fingirem" que são um arquivo, e podem ter todo o conteúdo que for escrito neles como um objeto tipo "bytes" (ou tipo "str") a qualquer momento:

```py
In [68]: from io import StringIO

In [70]: arq = StringIO()                                

In [71]: arq.write("um monte de texto\n")                
Out[71]: 18

In [72]: texto = arq.getvalue()                          

In [73]: print(texto)                                    
um monte de texto
```

As classes são feitas para você passar uma instância delas para código 
que espere um arquivo como um parâmetro - como por exemplo, as funções de salvar imagens da biblioteca "Pillow" - e quando a função retorna, você tem acesso aos bytes que teriam sido escritos em um arquivo ".jpg" no disco.

Atenção que o código que usa o arquivo não pode chamar o método `.close()` nele, senão não é possível recuperar o conteúdo. Mas se isso for acontecer, é fácil contornar criando uma subclasse muito simples, que "desligue" o método `close()` colocando um que não faz nada no lugar:

```py
In [82]: a = io.BytesIO                                                                          

In [83]: a = io.BytesIO()                                                                        

In [84]: a.write(b"teste")                                                                       
Out[84]: 5

In [85]: a.close()                                                                               

In [86]: a.getvalue()                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-a51238acd863> in <module>
----> 1 a.getvalue()

In [89]: class CloseProofIO(io.BytesIO): 
    ...:     def close(self): 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:          
    ...:                                                                                         

In [90]: b = CloseProofIO()                                                                      

In [91]: b.write(b"outro teste\n")                                                               
Out[91]: 12

In [92]: b.close()                                                                               

In [93]: b.getvalue()                                                                            
Out[93]: b'outro teste\n'
```

(*) Nunca vi oficialmente a terminologia "arquivo virtual" - mas acho que ela pode ser bem correta. Pelo menos eu entendi de primeira o conceito.

Comment: Exatamente isso, esse modulo resolveu o problema, o termo "arquivo virtual" é a forma leiga de tentar explicar, muito obrigado :D